# A simpler proof of evaluating the limsup of a standard normal sequence

Tags: statistics, measure-theory

Let $\{X_n\}$ be a sequence of i.i.d. random variables following the standard normal distribution. We need to prove that $$\limsup_n\left(\frac{X_n}{\sqrt{2\log n}}\right)=1$$

This is quite easy to show if you use Stirling's approximation and then Borel Cantelli lemma, but i dont want to use Stirling's approximation. Is there any simpler elegant solution?

Comment: You might want to show the method using Stirling's approximation.

Comment: Sorry, I made a huge mistake in my method. For using Borel Cantelli lemma I needed to show that $\sum_nP(\{X_n/\sqrt{2\log n}<1-\epsilon\})>\infty$ and $\sum_nP(\{X_n/\sqrt{2\log n}>1+\epsilon\})<\infty$. In order to evaluate $P(\{X_n/\sqrt{2\log n}<1-\epsilon\})$ I should have used the standard normal c.d.f., but instead I used the density. Big mistake! So can show me via any method at all!

Comment: Well, your comment delineates a clear road to the solution. You might want to pursue it since the tools needed to show the first series diverges are the same used to show the second series converges..

Comment: I can't show that the respective series' diverges and converges. Give some hints then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: If $X$ is standard normal then for every positive $x$,
$$
\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\frac{x}{1+x^2}\mathrm e^{-x^2/2}\leqslant P[X\geqslant x]\leqslant\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\frac1x\mathrm e^{-x^2/2}.
$$

Comment: Thats very helpful. But how do i show this inequality?

Comment: Try the "Related" questions suggested in a column on the right side of the present page.